# Get URL parameter from Google Analytics

Tags: java, php, android, html, google-analytics

I need a help, I have 3 android applications and I have a page that I call on my website.

Each app I call the page and I pass a parameter in the url, as follows:

```
/analytics.html?APP_NAME=APP_01
/analytics.html?APP_NAME=APP_02
/analytics.html?APP_NAME=APP_03
```

How can I get this parameter in Google Analytics? Look, the page is the same, I'd just like to target the APP

Comment: What did you tried? Can you add your code?

Comment: I do not have any code, I wanted to do this filtering in google analytics.
I'm sorry if I did not put the question clearly.

Comment: Check out this question here where the answer details how to get a query string value using JS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript